# How to create refs in react constructor function in es7?

Tags: reactjs

How to create ref and access the ref in es7.

```
class SomeComponent extends Component {
  state = {
    count: 0,
    this.myRef = React.createRef() //error
    myRef: React.createRef(), // Unused state field: 'myRef'  
  }

  render() {
    return <div ref={this.myRef} />; //error  
           <div ref={myRef} /> // error 'myRef' is not defined
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the ref in the constructor like this:

```
class SomeComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.myRef = React.createRef();
  }

  render() {
    return <div ref={this.myRef} />;
    }
 }
```

Here is the [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html).